# objective-c NSDateFormatter date from string returns null

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert this string @"August 8, 2013" to a NSDate but I keep getting NULL as my result:

```
strToConvert = @"August 8, 2013";
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY zzz"];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strToConvert];
```

Am I formatting it incorrectly?

Edit:

I changed the method to this:

```
- (NSDate*) convertStringToDate : (NSString*) strToConvert {


    NSError* error = nil;
    NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
    NSArray* arrDateMatches = [detector matchesInString:strToConvert options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strToConvert length])];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in arrDateMatches) {
        strToConvert =  [self convertDateToString:match.date];
    }

    NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strToConvert];
    return  myDate;

}
```

and it works fine. The only issue is I am getting a implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum NSTextCheckingType'... any idea of how to fix that warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NSDateFormatter` has the incorrect format. You need to match the format of the expected input:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking. So there's no way to have a generic string to date method?

Comment: Not with `NSDateFormatter`. You could have a look at `NSDataDetector`. See [this link](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/working-with-date-and-time-in-cocoa-part-2/) for more info.

Comment: Add a cast to the declaration of the dataDetector: `NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];`

Comment: I tried that and I get an ARC Restrictions error - implicit conversions not allowed - Edit: never mind, I was putting the cast in the wrong place.
This is a bug, right?

Comment: It does seem odd. You would think that the type expected is `NSTextCheckingType` rather than `NSTextCheckingTypes`. Not a perfect solution, but hopefully fixes the warning and you get the behaviour you're looking for.